# c++ compiling cppunit files and executing xml report

Tags: c++, g++, cppunit

I have some .cpp and .h files residing in path

~/NetBeansProjects/myApplication

```
main.cpp
person.cpp
person.h
```

and I have my cppunit .cpp and .h files residing in path

~/NetBeansProjects/myApplication/tests

```
TestCase.cpp
TestCase.h
finalresults.cpp
```

assuming that I am at ~ and I have cd to directory

```
/NetBeansProjects/myApplication in my terminal
```

I want to do a g++ along with my cppunit files TO GENERATE A XML REPORT of the results on cppunit test.

I add the XmlOutputter in my finalresults.cpp

```
        std::ofstream xmlFileOut("testResults.xml");
    XmlOutputter xmlOut(&collectedresults, xmlFileOut);
    xmlOut.write();

the command to use(as suggested) g++ -o finaltestresults person.cpp main.cpp tests/TestCase.cpp tests/finalresults.cpp -lcppunit
```

My program runs successfully but no xml is being created.

what additional steps do I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run:

`g++ -o finalresults main.cpp person.cpp tests/TestCase.cpp tests/finalresults.cpp -lcppunit`

Comment: I have a added XmOutPutter in my finalresults.cpp, I ran the command, it successfully builds my program but no xml is being created. what should I do?